# Click to make a call in dompdf

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, dompdf

I saw a suggestion to use following to make a call

```
<a href="tel:555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a>
```

But when I use the same in dompdf. It doesn't have a feature allowing me to click to call Option.

Can anyone share a snippet or line of code to make phone number with "click to call" feature in it.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Try and remove the dashes from the number in the href attribute.

Comment: I tried that too but no success yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution checking some other forum. And following is the code I used to to solve my issue.

```
<a href='tel:.5555555555'>555 555 5555</a>
```

Adding a dot before helped in pdf.

Answer (score -1):

Your code must be like:

```
<a href='tel:5555555555'>555 555 5555</a>
```